# how to udate window controls(NSTextField,NSCheckbox and etc) in binding manually

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I am working on an application in which i need to store all the NSObject subclass properties into plist file and then allow users to store it and restore it. We call it profile and it can restore the saved state of all the controls/views on the window in my application.

I have completed the storing/Restoring part, but the issue is when i am updating the class properties manually, it is not updating the control state Like checkboxs and others which is bind with the class property.

Please let me know how can i update the controls state, if its KVC/KVO updated programatically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read this guide [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

In particular read the section on "Automatic Versus Manual Support" which details how you need to change your properties so that you are KVO compliant.